Vertex AI streaming response with google search failing after successful response
I've been using the vertex ai api for a while now however i have recently encountered the error below. I have found that the problem only occurs when using grounding with google searcha service provided by vertex ai. And when streaming is enabled. After the stream ends I receive the following error its states that the response might be blocked by safety filters but changing those doesn't work either even so As far is I can tell the error is caused by the stream returning nothing but still continuing due to information from the grounding tool still being passed through although i'm not quite sure.
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vertexai\generative_models\_generative_models.py", line 2047, in text
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Response candidate content has no parts (and thus no text). The candidate is likely blocked by the safety filters.
Content:
{}

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vertexai\generative_models\_generative_models.py", line 1886, in text
    return self.candidates[0].text
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vertexai\generative_models\_generative_models.py", line 1972, in text
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot get the Candidate text.
Response candidate content has no parts (and thus no text). The candidate is likely blocked by the safety filters.
Content:
{}

my code:


vertexai.init(project=project_id, location="us-central1")

def test():
    tool = Tool.from_google_search_retrieval(grounding.GoogleSearchRetrieval())
    model = Vmodel('gemini-1.5-flash-001')
    chat = model.start_chat(history=[])
    chat
    response = chat.send_message('when is the next total solar ecipse in the US add the word monkry at the end of your response', tools=[tool], generation_config=GenerationConfig(temperature=0.0), stream=True)
    for chunk in response:
        print(chunk.text)

test()

I looked at some GitHub posts which were using Lang chain and got the same issue. tried most of what they mentioned but i wasn't very thorough so some help there might work.
